# How to setup multiple listening ip addresses on Trixbox

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk, trixbox, freepbx

I currently have added another ISP to our Data Center and have decided to setup an additional ethernet alias on our Trixbox for the 2nd ip address of our new provider.  From what I have read you can just edit the sip_general_custom.conf file and add the following information:

bindport = 5060 ; Port to bind to (SIP is 5060)

bindaddr = 0.0.0.0 ; Address to bind to (all addresses on machine)**

I cannot find anything else on Freepbx site besides this so I am just asking if this is the correct way to bind 2 ip address to Trixbox.  I of course have also setup an additional A record for the new provider in case you ask.

Comment: The bigger question you have to probably figure out is how will you deal with routing.  If you adding a second address from a different range what are you going to do to make the sure the correct gateway is selected.

Comment: Will for the gateway you config the adapter.  My question more or less I guess is how to setup SIP, my bad for not making that more pronounced.  I have a data center with some Linux boxes with 15 eth aliases with different providers I can handle the network part per say but the sip config I am not sure of.  You have to tell Trixbox how to listen to multiple ip's and so I am just validating the how to...Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct.  Once you define 0.0.0.0 as the listener, then trixbox will listen on both interface IP addresses for incoming connections.

This is the default behaviour.  It is actually the opposite option that you would need to change the config.  If you had two interfaces and only wanted to listen on one, then you would update bindaddr to have the specific IP address you wanted to listen on.